# bug with the way IE is displaying text after a picture

Tags: html, css

My page works great in Chrome and Firefox but its not being decoded well in IE. I fixed most bugs but I have one that I can seem to resolve. currently the picture is displayed and the  and the

is all bunched together next to it; The table is displayed fine. Here is the code:

```
<div id="page">
            <div id="slider">
                <!-- Here is where the pictures for the slider go -->
                <div id="PhotoSlider">
                    <ul class="bjqs">
                        <li><img src="images/test2.png"></img></li>
                        <li><img src="images/test1.png"></img></li>                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <!-- Java Script for the slider -->
            <script>                 
                $("#PhotoSlider").bjqs({
                    'height' : 286,
                    'width' : 1000,
                    'animationDuration' : 800,
                    'showMarkers' : true,
                    'useCaptions' : false,
                    'keyboardNav' : false,
                    'showControls' : false
                });
            </script>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div class="box">
                    <h1>Welcome!</h1><br/>
                        <p></p>
                        <p></p>
                </div>  
            </div>  

            <div id="contentRight">
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <!-- This is the newsletter form -->
            <div id="sidebar">
                <img align="left" src="images/kidsSmiling1.png"></img><br>
                <h2>Newsletter</h2>
                <p>Sign up to receive the lastest news and special offers</p>
                <table>             
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name<req>*</req>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" style="width:180"/>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name<req>*</req>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" style="width:180"/>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email<req>*</req>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input id="email" name="email" type="text" style="width:180"/>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p align="middle"><input align="middle" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="save()"  style="width:65"></P>
                <p><req>*</req>&nbsp;Required fields</p>                
            </div>
            <br class="clearfix" />
            <!-- Social media div -->
            <div id="media">
                <img align="right" src="images/facebookLogo.png"></img> <img align="right" src="images/twitterLogo.png"></img>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <div id="footer">
        Copyright &copy; 2012 Kaysville Dental | <a href="mailto:ToothDocPaul@msn.com?Subject=Customer Inquiry">Email Us</a> | Phone:(800) 376-2241 | 690 Main Street. Kaysville, Utah
    </div>
```

I wish I had the site live so that you guys could see but unfortunately its just on localhost... The problem is with the image and the text below. For some reason the Image is displayed and the text is all on the left side and not in its own paragraph. Here is the CSS for that portion:

```
#sidebar {
background: white;
padding: 0px 5px 0px 50px;
margin-left: 0;
border-right: 1px solid #C0C0C0 ;
float: left;
width: 312px;
}


#sidebar p {
font-size: 12px;
margin-bottom: 0.5em
}

#sidebar img{
margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
#sidebar req {
font-size: 12px;
color: red;
}

#sidebar td{
padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
font-size: 14px;
}

#sidebar h2{
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#contentRight {
background: white;
padding: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
float: right;
width: 550px;
}
```

The last "contentRight" is the div that goes on the other side of the sidebar(to the right)
so basically you have the side bar with a picture and a little form underneath and then to the right there is a section with just text

Comment: hehe i find it humorous that you close the img tag with </img> but the br is just <br>  Anyway I put your code in a fiddle with some random image http://jsfiddle.net/Y9yf8/

Comment: Tables are for data, not forms or layouts. Use labels and unordered lists instead. http://woork.blogspot.ca/2008/06/form-elements-design-using-css-and-list.html

Comment: please explain more clearly what exactly is hapenning?

Comment: I think Internet Explorer might be happening.

Comment: No, they're more like crutches.

Comment: The side bar is big enough to show a picture and then to have a little form underneath. The problem is that I'm getting the picture and then the heading and the text is all bunched up net to it to the right. The table is then displayed underneath like it was meant to.

Comment: @hera87 could you paste a more complete version of your html code? don't need all the content but at least the structure

Comment: @Huangism If you run http://jsfiddle.net/Y9yf8/ on ie you can see the problem... it runs fine in chrome though

Comment: @hera87 see my answer for solution

Comment: @Huangism I added the whole thing but I got rid of the text... thats why youll see empty <p>

Comment: @hera87 see my answer, some missing tags plus the align left was messing it up in IE 7. Did not check 8 but it should work

Comment: @Wug As great as it sounds to never need to use IE, there are instances where that just isn't possible. It is still a very widely used browser especially in a corporate setting. As much as people hate Internet Exploder, you still have to make sure your site is compatible with it to seem remotely professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing td closing tags on the second cell of each row and also get rid of align="left" on the img tag

see http://jsfiddle.net/Y9yf8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign `float: left` to the `<img>` tag and then `float: left; width: 100%;` to the `<h2>` tag...

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9yf8/3/ =)

P.S. or do as Huangism said...